# webview: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, webview, electron

In my electron app I am setting a webview. This is a snippet from index.html:

```
  <webview
    class="hide"
    preload="./preload.js"
    nodeintegration
  ></webview>

  <script>
    require('./renderer.js');
  </script>
```

In main.js I have set `nodeIntegration:false` for the BrowserWindow, but the app doesn't start, as I get this error in webview's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If I remove `nodeIntegration:false` from main.js, it works, but I don't want to expose node API.

(P.S.: the remote web app pointed by the webview is using jQuery. Maybe a conflict?)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `nodeIntegration : false` command like `require` won't be set.

It seems like you have 2 possibilities :

- let `nodeIntegration: false` and deal with it
- call your js file as if you were in browser : `<script src="pathToFile"></script>`

https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron here they explain what really does `nodeIntegration`

Comment: For your option#1: I don't know how to deal with it, as it will expose Node API in the web app.  For option#2: it doesn't work as it will generate a message `"require is not defined"` in renderer.js

Comment: then you should use browserify : 

http://browserify.org/

It enables you to use `require` in js front file.